# Creating templates in rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to create a custom template but it will not show up.

I already tried to follow https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/template-structure.html but could not figure it out. I had created a skeleton.rmd and template.yaml but do not know if I need to put them in a special folder.

When creating a new rmarkdown file i want my template to be a choice in the "from template" tab.

Comment: If you want to be able to choose it as "from template," you have to follow the steps in 17.1 and 17.2 of that same document, not just 17.3 (which is what you linked to)

Comment: I also followed 17.1 and 17.2 creating the skelton.rmd and template.yaml

Comment: In an R package? How I read chapter 17 there was that you needed to make an R package, install it, and then it would be available to choose on the "from template" table. I have recently wanted this functionality for a couple templates not provided by anyone else, and you can see what I've done to make this work for me: https://github.com/duckmayr/draft

Comment: what do you mean install the r package. i made it and do not know what to do after that to get it into the "from template" table

Answer (score 5):

The way I have been able to make this work is to create an R package, then place the template files within the package structure as described in [Chapter 17 of Yihui's R Markdown book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/document-templates.html). I then install the R package via `devtools::install()` (though there are other options).

So, for example, what I did for a particular journal submission format (which you can find at https://github.com/duckmayr/draft) was:

1. Create an R package via `library(devtools); create_package("draft")`. I called my package `draft`, so you'd change that part to your package name.
2. Add template meta information in `inst/rmarkdown/templates/jop/template.yaml`
3. Add the Rmd skeleton in `inst/rmarkdown/templates/jop/skeleton/skeleton.Rmd` (you'd change the `jop` part of that to whatever your template is named.
4. Add my custom Pandoc template in `inst/rmarkdown/templates/jop/resources/template.tex`
5. Install the package via `devtools::install("draft")`

Then I was able to use the template as you are wanting to ("create from template").

Comment: would you know why this is not working. My error when running devtools::create("draft") is Error: 'create' is not an exported object from 'namespace:devtools'

Comment: @abtc378 That's my error. I typed this up pretty quick and was a little sloppy. Fixing this now.

Comment: @abtc378 The answer is now updated to fix that issue

Comment: for part 2 what is template meta information and when you say add is that just doing save as and putting them in the folders you have listed out?

Comment: also when you run library(devtools); create_package("draft") is it supposed to create another window? I am confused

Comment: @abtc378 If you want to prevent the opening of a new window you can use `create_package("draft", rstudio = FALSE, open = FALSE)`. When I say add I do mean saving them in the folders I've listed out. The template meta information is discussed at the beginning of 17.1 of Yihui's book

Comment: is this popup suppossed to happen New project 'draft' is nested inside an existing project './', which is rarely a good idea.
Do you want to create anyway?

1: No way
2: Absolutely not
3: Definitely