# Where does R store the markdown templates?

Tags: r, templates, r-markdown, reproducible-research

I have an R markdown template (`skeleton.Rmd` and `template.yaml`) that I would like to use. The various documents that describe the creation of templates (e.g., [here](https://chester.rbind.io/ecots2k16/template_pkg/), [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/document-templates.html), and [here](https://rstudio.github.io/rstudio-extensions/rmarkdown_templates.html)) all say that templates are either created in the working directory (e.g., by using the [use_rmarkdown_template()](https://use_rmarkdown_template()) function) or in the `inst/rmarkdown/templates` directory of a package (I assume the package your are developing).

I work on a Mac, and my working directory is usually the Desktop (I know - someone is going to say this is bad for whatever reason, but it's the way my broken brain works), and I don't want the `inst/rmarkdown/templates` directory on the Desktop.

I have a large number of templates installed (i.e., that are available from `File` -> `New File` -> `R Markdown` -> `From Template`), but I cannot seem to find anything related to those names when I search for them.

**EDIT**: Here is a solution that works. I don't know if it's kosher or not, but I get the behavior I'm after.

The path is: `Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/[*note1*]/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/templates/[*HERE*]`

Note 1: If you have multiple versions of R installed, pick the right one. I'm not sure if "Current" works or not. Obviously no brackets or asterisks.

Note 2: The double `rmarkdown/rmarkdown` is not a typo.

At this point, you take the directory that contains *just* your template (i.e., the `template.yaml` file and the subdirectory called `skeleton` with the file `skeleton.Rmd` in it) and put it where I put HERE (again, no brackets or asterisks).

Restart R. When you open a new markdown file, your template will be available in the list - no unique working directory and no package.

If anyone knows of problems with this, please let me know. Otherwise, I think we should propagate this! (I don't have a solution for Windows, but I'm sure it would be similar.)

Comment: You need to create your own package to have a custom template. When you create your package, that's where the `inst/markdown/templates` folder will go. Perhaps this existing answer will give you more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57361395/creating-templates-in-rmarkdown

Comment: I saw that before I posted. When you install other templates (which don't require a package or a working directory), where do they go?

Comment: There are no such things as templates that don't come from a package. The RStudio UI only shows you templates that are provided by R packages as far as I can tell. Do you know of a case where that's not true?

Comment: @MrFlick - Please see edits above.

Comment: Your method basically hacks the existing `rmarkdown` package. Anything you add there will get wiped out when you update your `rmarkdown` package version. It's generally not a good idea to attempt to directly edit code inside an installed pacakge. It's much easier and safer just to create your own package which has the templates you want.

Comment: @MrFlick - Understood. I will learn to create my own package. Thank you!